# Growth function and one misunderstanding point?!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I have a question about Growth and Asymptotic notation topic.

My question is as follows:

$2^n$ > $n^{log_2{(n)}}$ is True.

> anyone could say how we can deduce that this fact is true?

Comment: Did you intend to write $n^{\log_2n}$?

Comment: what do u mean by your sentence @JohnWaylandBales?

Comment: $\log_2^n$ is a meaningless expression.

Comment: You still have the $n$ in the superscript, just parenthesized now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant $\log_2(n)$ and not $\log_2^n$. If I'm right, then take logarithms, say in base 2 (just for convenience). On the left you have $n$. On the right you have $\log_2(n)^2$. Now use L'Hospital's rule to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\log_2(n)^2}$. From the result of this and the fact that $2^x$ is an increasing function, you conclude that eventually $2^n$ is larger than $C n^{\log_2(n)}$ for any $C>0$.

If your question is about whether the statement is true for $C=1$ and *any* $n$ then that is another matter.

Comment: I'm talking about O notation. first statement is O of second?

Comment: @MinaSaber What I said implies that $n^{\log_2(n)}=O(2^n)$ (in fact stronger).

Comment: yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve these problems is visually. if we graph both solutions we see the $2^n$ (in orange) solution eventually outgrows $n^{nlog_2(n)}$ in blue.

[image: plotes]

Comment: Big O notation means coefficients don't matter in fact you can plot these graphs with any coefficient and $a*2^n$ still out grows $b*log_2(n)^2$ I used coefficients of 1.

Comment: I used mathematica